# How does new android Apps get discovered?

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is some "New Apps" category in the Android market so that new Apps get the chance to be exposed.

It exists in App Store and WF7 and I couldn't find such a category in Android. All it shows is the most popular paid/free Apps.

If it doesn't exist, what chance does new Android Apps have to survive, unless it's already a familiar App from different platforms?

Is there any other way I am missing to get that minimal exposure?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information on what constitutes an on-topic question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may well be scolded for posting in the wrong section for this...

But to answer your question, I believe there used to be a "new apps" section but it was removed when the market was updated fairly recently. It's a slow process, but you should make sure your app has a good name, and that you promote it as much as you can.

The best way to make an app successful it to make a really good one. Then you'll hopefully get a kind of snowball effect with people buying it/downloading it. I've just recently released my first app to the market within the last week and it's frustrating not really knowing how good it actually is because it hasn't had much exposure.

The main thing is time, it takes time to be recognised, but if it's very good then it will get there. There are ways to speed the process up but these are rarely free (eg. advertising).

If you search on google for "submit android app for review" then you'll get a whole host of app review sites. You send them some info and the apk, and if they like the idea they may post a review of the app which can help you gain exposure.